# Docusign API attach supplemental documents

Tags: c#, docusignapi

How does one go about sending a supplemental document along with the document to sign? 
the use case: 
We are sending a contract for the user to sign, and would like to send the person som startup/welcome information aswell.

What ive tried:

**Creating the attachment**

```
                Attachment attachment = new Attachment()
                {
                    data = Convert.ToBase64String(docStorageDto.DocumentBlob),
                    name = ConversionUtil.MakeLegalFileName(docStorageDto.OrigFilename),
                    attachmentId = displayIndex.ToString() + index,
                    attachmentType= "pdf"
                };
```

**Tried to add it to the envelope**

```
    envelopeDefinition.attachments = new List<Attachment>(){ attachment };
    envelopeDefinition.envelopeAttachments = new List<Attachment>(){ attachment };
```

**Tried to add it to the "Signer" object**

```
    RecipientAttachment att = new RecipientAttachment()
    {
        data = attachment.data,
        name = attachment.name,
        attachmentId = attachment.attachmentId,
        attachmentType = attachment.attachmentType
    };

    recipientSigner.recipientAttachments = new List<RecipientAttachment>(){att};
```

All with no luck, fields does not seem to be used? Where does one need to add the attachments/supplemental documents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A supplemental document does not use an `attachment` object.

To add a supplemental document to an envelope:

1. Read the [docs](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/concepts/documents#supplemental-documents).
2. Create a `document` object, same as for any other document.
3. Set the `signerMustAcknowledge` attribute of the document object to one of:

   - `no_interaction` No recipient action is required.
   - `view` The recipient is required to view the document.
   - `accept` The recipient is required to accept the document by selecting accept during signing, but is not required to view the document.
   - `no_interaction` No recipient action is required.

Answer (score 1):

For future reference, Larry K is right. 
supplemental documents does not use the attachment properties, but is just sent as a regular document. What i needed to set for it not to be included in the combined document etc. was to set these properties on the "Document" object:

```
includeInDownload = "false";
display = "modal";
```